# Pulling data from google analytics to spreadsheet

Tags: google-analytics

So, I am trying to pull some data from google analytics into a google sheet. The thing is, the data I am trying to pull is different queries. Example:
keyword1 + keyword2 + keyword3. GA returns this hereafter:

```
Impression Clicks CTR Average Top Position 
    xxx     yyy     zzzz          xyz
```

Is there a way to automate this? It's gonna be the same keywords over and over again.

Comment: Did you try the analytics spreadsheet add-on: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on  (and use a filter with a regexp, where keyword=keyword1 OR keyword2 etc) ? I'm not quite sure want you want your report to look like, but the add-on is the easiest way to automate reports.

Answer (score 1):

Install the analytics addon that Eike referenced.

1) First create a new report. From within Google sheet select: Add-ons > Google Analytics > Create new report.

2) Then you need to configure your report. I don't know the interval or date range you want to pull data for so this is just an example to get you going:

**Report Name   CPC Keywords Test**

- Type core
- View (Profile) ID / ids  ga:1234567 (Should be the view id)
- Start Date   4/28/2016 (you could enter =today()-30 to make it dynamic
  today -30days)
- End Date 5/27/2016 (you could enter =today()-1)
- Last N Days
- Metrics  ga:impressions,ga:adClicks (you can add more fields here)
- Dimensions   ga:keyword,ga:medium
- Sort -ga:impressions
- Filters  ga:keyword=~.*donkeys.*;ga:medium=~cpc (you need to modify
  the filter ga:keyword=~ to include more keywords that you want. In
  this case it gives med all keywords from medium cpc that include
  donkeys. Even broad match operators of adwords + e.g.)

If you wonder what the ga: fields should be named you can always test in the Google Query Explorer: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

If you are new to this I recommend running the report from the GA add-on and do this in increments. If regular expressions or your having trouble please include more specifics and I can help?

3) If the output is what you want all you need to do is to set the report schedule. Add-On > Google Analytics > Schedule reports and you should be getting what you want.

Comment: Yeah, so I basically want a report that gives me the # of impressions, # of clicks and CTR based on a set of search queries. Here is a screenshot from GA, that shows what I want automated: https://gyazo.com/faa7e6f34bfec7dae85a321ad3d7d767